# Newbie Make new window redirect confirm addition of points

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<a href="index.php?module=voteforpoints&action=vote&sid=<?php echo $site->site_id; ?>" target="_blank">Get 1 Point</a>
```

I own a game server and we get ranked by doing vote points.

It's a script that whenever a player clicks this, a vote point will be added. But most of the time, the player just click the link and not "vote" because they still accumulate points.

My question is, How can I make that script redirect to a new window, and that new window will have the link that when the player click it, the vote point will be added.

Thanks, I'm new to HTML and PHP but I'm good at CSS :)

Comment: why this script doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding accessing "index.php?module=voteforpoints&action=vote&sid=..." gives one point

try to create a new page, say vote.php, containing the actual voting link: `<a href="index.php?module=voteforpoints&action=vote&sid=<?php echo $site->site_id; ?>" >Get 1 Point</a>` - without the 'target'

now replace your old link with: `<a href="vote.php" target"_blank" >Get 1 Point</a>`